# Error response from daemon: Ports are not available - Apache Superset

Tags: docker-compose, apache-superset

After run the command "docker-compose up" getting below error. Is there any solution.?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your config is trying to access port 5432. which is unavailable. It is probably busy with another application, for example, PostgreSQL is already running